# What columns are available for the prediction/output class in ml.net

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm running binary classifiers in ML.net. The output class looks like below, it has a "PredictedLabel" and through trial and error I've discovered the that "score" and "probability" are also valid. Where are the valid properties documented? And is there a property that I can use (with a corresponding name on the input data class) that will allow me to store a row id on the input data that will be output with the prediction?

Thanks

```
public class TargetData
{
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public float Score { get; set; }
    public float Probability { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This comment in an issue may be the closest to documentation - https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/376#issuecomment-399282699

Comment: Ah that's useful, thanks. No Id though which is surprising - something that AWS ML provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ML.NET relies on [schema comprehension](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/SchemaComprehension.md) to map the fields of an object to columns of a data view and back.

There is no limit on which columns your data view may have. For example, you could define your example class to be

```
public class Example
{
    // Let's say your features are floats:
    public float FeatureA;
    public float FeatureB;
    // ...
    public bool Label;

    // Here's an arbitrary RowId column.
    public string RowId; 
}
```

The `RowId` column will be created, and propagated all the way through the training, and it will be retained in the resulting model.
In order to read it back, just declare the field/property with the same name in your output class:

```
public class TargetData
{
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public float Score { get; set; }
    public float Probability { get; set; }

    public string RowId { get; set; }
}
```

The only limitation is on the allowed types: for example, you cannot declare `GUID` fields etc. The [schema comprehension](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/SchemaComprehension.md) doc and the other linked docs define precisely which types are allowed.

Comment: There is also this art of the question: `"Where are the valid properties documented?"` - which should depend on the type of "trainers and tasks" used?

Comment: It seem to be listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/resources/tasks

Comment: Thanks for linking to the schema comprehension documentation, seems like it's not anywhere in the msdn official docs for ML.NET!